# Playwright doesn't find dynamic element

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to login on buff.163.com. Playwright does click on the Login button but it seems like it can't find the login with password hyperlink. My current code looks like this:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=50)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://buff.163.com/market/csgo#tab=selling&page_num=1")
    page.locator("xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li/a").click()
    a_locator = page.locator('a:has-text("Login with password")').click
    page.pause()
```

It should click on the hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that button is inside an iframe.

[image]

You could do something like this:

```
page.frameLocator('iframe').locator('a:has-text("Login with password")').click()
```